# How can I get the element of a list that has a minimum/maximum property in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have the following array in Python:

```
points_list = [point0, point1, point2]
```

where each of `points_list` is of the type:

```
class point:
    __init__(self, coord, value):
        self.coord = numpy.array(coord)
        self.value = value
# etc...
```

And a function:

```
def distance(x,y):
    return numpy.linalg.norm(x.coord - y.coord)
```

And I have a point `point_a` defined elsewhere.  Now I want to find the point in `points_list` that's closest to `point_a`.

Other than a loop, what's the best way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
min(points_list, key=lambda x: distance(x, point_a))
```

**To answer a question in comment**: `lambda` is indeed necessary here since [function specified as a `key` argument needs to accept only a single argument](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#min).

*However*, since your `point_a` is essentially global you could "hard-code" it into the `distance` function:

```
>>> point_a = point([1, 2, 3], 5)
>>> def distance(x):
    return numpy.linalg.norm(x.coord - point_a.coord)
```

This way you could pass `distance` as a key argument skipping `lambda` altogether.

```
>>> min(points_list, key=distance)
```

Comment: Another Python function I didn't know about :) +1. I guess a loop would only be beneficial if you intend to calculate both min and max at the same time.

Comment: @Andre: I think the better option would be to use `sort` with the same `key` argument and get first and last elements.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Ok.. maybe you want min, max and average :-)

Comment: You are still looping, you just have min() do it for you.

Comment: I didn't know that `min()` accepts a `key` parameter.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the lambda function really necessary?  why can't I just have `key = distance(x, point_a))`?  Is it because the key function has to be a function of a single argument?